# MySQL view to generate monthly bonus

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a web site for marketing company. As per their requirement, when a customer makes a booking. A certain amount of bonus is distributed between employees based on 
their hierarchy. The distribution starts from 60 days after booking and bonus is given
for 24 months.

The tables are

> bookings

```
bid      book_date  
 1        2012-05-09
 2        2012-05-10
```

> bonus

```
bid   empid    amount
1       1        300 
1       2        400  
2       2        300
2       3        400
```

Is it possible to write mysql views that generates monthly bonus an employee gets
for every month. I didn't find solution on how to make update with mysql view. Any hint
will of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Inner join on bid and filter to only include eligible bonuses by comparing the book date to today's date. If today's date is less than 60 days after or more than 24 months plus 60 days after the original book date, exclude it. (You can go to mySQL.com to learn more about how to manipulate dates in mySQL. I forget...)

You will be left with multiple rows containing only emp id and amount. In the second round, use a "select sum(amount) from (...put your other query here...) group by empid" to get the aggregate bonus per employee.

This approach (and I think any solution) requires a nested SQL statement, and so if you're not comfortable with that syntax you can use that term to explore in google or SO. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks,but it will difficult for newbie like me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of view, I would suggest is write mysql function which will return the bonus by accepting the employee ID.

Using mysql function you will have more room to write logic and PL/SQL.

Comment: I'll have to look into that.Thank you,very much.